# Covering an Interval through Transformations

Tags: geometry, functions, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems

Consider the the real number $k$ which satisfies $0 < k < 1$.

We are given two transformations $T_1(x) = kx$ and $T_2(x) = (1-k)x + k$.

Consider the set of real numbers over the interval $[0, 1]$.  Now consider some smaller interval $[a, b] \in [0, 1]$.  Given a starting point x = k, the goal is to show that through a sequence of the above transformations, a point can be reached that is in the interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: I suggest the dynamical systems tag, also remove the logic tag it's irrelevant.